# Auto-login for Raspberry Pi

Tags: keyboard, login, kali, debug

Let me first say I have a rpi 2 model B with the official 7" display and a old tablet lipo battery. It has Kali Rolling on it. I have tinkered with it quite a bit at this point...

I need to auto login to the user account "admin"

I have done the tutorial online to auto login Kali Linux by editing the dameon.conf file and unmasking the 2 lines (in my case I changed root to admin (admin is my user account). But it still shows the login screen. My goal is t get to the desktop without a keyboard. Thanks!!!

The daemon.conf is exactly how it was default except this section was changed, as follows:

```
[daemon] # Enabling automatic login       AutomaticLoginEnable = true AutomaticLogin = admin
```

Comment: Given that Kali is a security based distro removing the pssword is a bad idea.

Comment: It's only for traffic analysis

Comment: As @SteveRobillard suggested can't you try using the normal user. I haven't tried Kali in my case its `pi` for raspbian. Then provide some elevated privilege (sudo) as per your need.

Comment: @Varad A G that is pretty much what I am going for, I want to have to 'sudo' for the things I want to have elevated privileges.

Comment: @BionicBouncer can you add the /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf file in the question. I think you would have edited this file

Comment: @Varad A G I changed it so you can now see what I edited!

Comment: @BionicBouncer I have added a pretty length answer since I cannot comment that big. Can you check out if you have followed these steps. The autologin stuff differes for `KDE` and `GNOME`.

Comment: Yes, one sec while I boot my pi

Answer (score 1):

Setting up of Autologin changes from `GNOME` and `KDE`

Step 1: Identify the Desktop Environment that is used.

```
echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
```

This should tell you which environment that is used at login.

For GNOME Users

```
1. sudo vi /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf

  [daemon]
  # Enabling automatic login
    AutomaticLoginEnable = true
    AutomaticLogin = <username>

2. Save the file
3. Reboot.
```

For KDE Users

```
1. sudo vi /etc/kde4/kdm/kdmrc
2. Add the below lines to the end-of-file. Don't forget to change the **AutoLoginUser**


[X-:0-Core]
AllowRootLogin=true
AutoLoginAgain=true
AutoLoginDelay=0
AutoLoginEnable=true
AutoLoginLocked=false
AutoLoginUser=<username>
ClientLogFile=.xsession-errors

3. Save the file and reboot.
```

Comment: I did the GNOME one and changed it but still don't auto login (I tried root and admin usernames)

Comment: @BionicBouncer Can you give me the OS details from `uname -a` command output. I can try this out today on my RPi and get back to you.

Comment: Output was : Linux Kali 4.1.19-v7 #1 SMP Tue Mar 15 15:10:00 CDT 2016 armv71 GNU/Linux

Comment: Is there a way I can run a verbose log of the startup to see what happens when it gets to the point to automatically login?

Comment: @BionicBouncer I am not sure if you will be able nail it down that way easily. I am downloading the Kali Linux 2.1.2 , the latest one to test it out. I had switched Raspbian yesterday :)

Comment: isn't 4.*.*-v* the new one (not 2.*.*-v*

Comment: If so I need to update

Comment: I picked up the ARM based one from the link https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-arm-images/. I think this is the latest one. Let me know if you using a different link

Comment: No thats the link, does yours show the 4.1.19v7 in uname -a?

Comment: I poked around a bit and still nothing.

Comment: @BionicBouncer I am sorry I totally went out of the loop. Can you give the link from where you downloaded the image. I downloaded the other one 2.*.*.*. I just need to use the same one that you have used.

Comment: The download link I used was the one you had mentioned before. Not sure why it says 4.1.19v7

Comment: @BionicBouncer I will update you on this today.

Comment: I found the answer, read my post

Comment: @BionicBouncer Oho that's great. But you should have seen it way back when you would have checked the command `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION`. Did it not return the correct interface?

Comment: That's the thing, even after I got auto login working it still says GNOME

Answer (score 1):

The original answer can be found at [this link](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?30021-Kali-2016-1-quot-light-quot-root-autologin)

Basically I was on XFCE and did not realize it. You must edit the lights.conf file to allow auto login. Instructions on that site.